# confusion regarding the past tense of 'lassen'

Tags: verb, tense

I just learnt that

> hat sich scheiden lassen

is correct whereas

> hat sich scheiden gelassen

is incorrect.

But at the same time

> er hat mich in Ruhe gelassen

is correct but

> er hat mich in Ruhe lassen

is incorrect.

I am really confused. Why is it that sometimes 'gelassen' is the correct one and sometimes 'lassen' is the correct one?

Comment: Just as a side comment: "gelassen" exists also as an *Adjektiv/Adverb*, where it means "calm(-ly)": "er hörte gelassen zu" = "he listened calmly".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first example, *lassen* is used as modal verb¹, in the second as full verb. Infinitive is used instead of the past participle for modal verbs at the end of the clause, this is called the [Ersatzinfinitiv](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ersatzinfinitiv).

> hat sich scheiden lassen

has *lassen* as modal verb, with "scheiden" as the full verb.

> hat mich in Ruhe gelassen.

has *lassen* as full verb, in the phrase "in Ruhe lassen". *lassen* can also be used as full verb with the meaning of "not doing", as in

> hat es gelassen.

as full verb. The same holds for other modal verbs, e.g.

> hat sich scheiden können.

with *können* als modal verb, and

> hat es nicht gekonnt.

with *können* als full verb.

¹(Edit): and some other verbs that directly take infinitive.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Then I suppose the 'lassen' in 'ich ließ den Wagen in der Garage stehen' and 'Sie lässt alles liegen' are also modal verbs. What about the sentence 'Ich muss sie irgendwo liegen gelassen haben'? Do we have two modal verbs here?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is an example of the [Ersatzinfinitiv](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ersatzinfinitiv). This happens most often with modal verbs, but the article lists others: brauchen, heißen, lassen, sehen, hören, fühlen, helfen. To me the basic rule is that a participle following an infinitive at the end of a sentence becomes another infinitive. As rules go it seems kind of random, even by German standards, but a rule is a rule.

Comment: I'd also note that "lassen" is not normally classified as modal, but that depends on your definitions. I would call it "modal with accusative object", though sometimes it's just a transitive verb: *Lass mich in Ruhe.* There are many verbs which achieve the same functionality with a 'zu' clause, for example "zwingen".

Comment: I learned in school this "list of modal verbs": können, mögen, müssen, dürfen, wollen, sollen and lassen. @Dennis: yes, there can be more than one modal verbs in a sentence, e.g. this well-known aphorism by Karl Valentin: "Wollen hätten wir schon mögen, aber dürfen haben wir uns nicht getraut."

Comment: @RDBury I saw on [this page](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~deutsch/Grammatik/Lassen/Lassen.html/) that there is something called Modal auxiliary. Maybe that's what you call 'modal with accusative object'?

Comment: @bakunin it is interesting that when we have a modal verb and a modal auxiliary in a sentence, then Ersatzinfinitiv does not work anymore, as in the example 'ich muss sie irgendwo liegen gelassen haben'.

Comment: @Dennis - Your link didn't work on my browser, but [this](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~deutsch/Grammatik/Lassen/Lassen.html) does. A "modal auxiliary" is what Bruce Duncan calls a modal verb. And yes, grammar is hard enough without everyone coming up with their own names for things, some having slightly different meanings, but here we are.

Comment: @Dennis The "liegen lassen" example is really interesting: If we switch out "liegen" for another verb, say "reinigen", for me, both "er muss das Zimmer reinigen lassen haben" and "er muss das Zimmer reinigen gelassen haben" don't sound quite right. But "liegen lassen" is no problem: I guess, we are treating it like separable verb here:)

If we use Ersatzinfinitiv even on modal verbs that are not the end, is an edge case that can't really be decided. I mean, we would have to use modal+haben+modal+verb: two modals and perfect in one clause. Even native speakers are not too sure about this.